# let arr=['123', '456', '789']; Используя map преобр. этот массив в следующий: let arr=[ [1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9] ];где у меня ошибка в коде?

Tags: javascript

```
  let arr = ['123', '456', '789'];
  let arr1 = [];

  let result = arr.map(function(elem){
    
  elem.split("");
  return arr1.push(Number(elem));

  });
   

 console.log(result);
```

Comment: Ошибка в первую очередь в написании корректного вопроса

Answer (score 3):

Зачем всякие `push` в какой-то массив `arr1`, если `map` уже возращает массив?

Зачем `Number` применять над `elem`, а не над каждым числом, которые произошли в результате `split`?

Результат `elem.split("")` заносится куда? Кажется просто в небо.

`return arr1.push` --- что должно здесь вернуться на ваш взгляд, если `push` возвращает длину объекта, для которого был вызван данный метод.

```js
let arr = ['123', '456', '789'];
let result = arr.map(elem => elem.split("").map(singleNumber => Number(singleNumber)));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
const arr = ['123', '456', '789'];
const result = arr.map(elem => elem.split("").map(Number));
console.log(result);
```